Excel =MIN(INDEX(( returning wrong value
I'm trying to return earliest date from a range by using the following formula:
=MIN(INDEX((donations_tracker!$A$2:$A$15 = A4)\*(donations_tracker!$D$2:$D$15),,,))
The formula returns 1899-12-30 for all instead of 2022-01-31 for example. I've included an

I am also doing a similar calculation for the same range with MAX(INDEX(( on another column, which returns correct values.
I have tried changing the format but it doesn't help.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Try removing index

Use MINIFS instead:  =MINIFS(donations_tracker!$D$2:$D$15,donations_tracker!$A$2:$A$15,A4) then make sure there are no 0 in column D where the criteria is met.

The reason you get those is your INDEX is returning 0 when (donations_tracker!$A$2:$A$15 = A4) is false and the minimum of a date and 0 is 0.  0 formatted as a date is 1899-12-30 to Excel.

This worked, thank you!

As you have not provided an example, I assume your donations_tracker sheet looks something like this:



Donor
Amount
Type
Donation Date




John
100
Cash
2022-01-15


Jane
150
Check
2022-01-20


John
200
Cash
2022-02-10


Jane
250
Check
2022-02-15


John
300
Cash
2022-03-05


Jane
350
Check
2022-03-10


John
400
Cash
2022-04-01


Jane
450
Check
2022-04-05


John
500
Cash
2022-05-01


Jane
550
Check
2022-05-05


John
600
Cash
2022-06-01


Jane
650
Check
2022-06-05


John
700
Cash
2022-07-01


Jane
750
Check
2022-07-05



I’m not sure why you have used index, but for the "First donation date" and "Last donation date," you can use these formulas:
=MIN(IF((donations_tracker!$A$2:$A$15 = A2), donations_tracker!$D$2:$D$15))
=MAX(IF((donations_tracker!$A$2:$A$15 = A2), donations_tracker!$D$2:$D$15))

You use IF to match the condition (name of the donor) and MIN to find the earliest date in the array.
Result:




First donation date
Last donation date




John
2022-01-15
2022-07-01


Jane
2022-01-20
2022-07-05



